# Supermicro Smash power management commands don't work

Tags: ipmi, supermicro, bmc

SMASH power management commands don't work for me.

For example, I've tried the following in attempt to power on the chassis:

```
start /system1/pwrmgtsvc1
```

It says "start..done." but the server chassis is not powered on.  Same thing when I tried it for stop/reset as well.

Comment: Please specify BMC firmware version, which causes this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this was an IPMI firmware issue.  Contact Supermicro for the latest firmware to fix the problem.